# How to group when using aggregates in the select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run the following code, but receive an error because of the last field in the SELECT statement that contains both an aggregate condition and a normal condition
trunc(d.ead_date)- trunc(max(d.pickup_date_ts)) AS diff_ead_cpt_max

The Error is basically saying aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY clause. If I remove the max, then it would work but then I would not get the right results.

```
SELECT
       w1.physical_country origin_country,
       a.leg_warehouse_id lm_warehouse_id,


       b.leg_warehouse_id fl_warehouse_id,


       c.plane_name,
       k.leg_ware,
       k.last_ds,

       trunc(a.ead_date) ead_date,
       max(d.pickup_date_ts) max_cpt,
       to_char(max(d.pickup_date_ts),'HH24:MI') max_cpt_time,
       trunc(max(d.pickup_date_ts)) max_cpt_date,
       trunc(d.ead_date)- trunc(max(d.pickup_date_ts)) AS diff_ead_cpt_max

from
       final_leg a 
       inner join dest_leg b 
       on a.shipment_id = b.shipment_id and a.route_id = b.route_id
       inner join sc_execution_eu.o_detailed_routes_v2 d 
       on a.shipment_id = d.shipment_id and a.route_id = d.route_id and d.leg_sequence_id = 0
       left join plane_leg c
       on a.shipment_id = c.shipment_id and a.route_id = c.route_id
       left join warehouse_attributes w1
       on a.route_warehouse_id = w1.warehouse_id
       left join warehouse_attributes w2
       on b.leg_warehouse_id = w2.warehouse_id
       RIGHT JOIN list_legs_ds k
       on a.route_warehouse_id = k.leg_ware AND a.leg_warehouse_id = k.last_ds


group by
       1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11
```

Comment: It should work if you remove 11 from group by clause.

Comment: Using positions in the `GROUP BY` clause does not appear to be valid [Oracle syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` the non-aggregated values and use the column names:

```sql
SELECT
       w1.physical_country origin_country,
       a.leg_warehouse_id lm_warehouse_id,
       b.leg_warehouse_id fl_warehouse_id,
       c.plane_name,
       k.leg_ware,
       k.last_ds,
       trunc(a.ead_date) ead_date,
       max(d.pickup_date_ts) max_cpt,
       to_char(max(d.pickup_date_ts),'HH24:MI') max_cpt_time,
       trunc(max(d.pickup_date_ts)) max_cpt_date,
       trunc(d.ead_date)- trunc(max(d.pickup_date_ts)) AS diff_ead_cpt_max

from
       final_leg a 
       inner join dest_leg b 
       on a.shipment_id = b.shipment_id and a.route_id = b.route_id
       inner join sc_execution_eu.o_detailed_routes_v2 d 
       on a.shipment_id = d.shipment_id and a.route_id = d.route_id and d.leg_sequence_id = 0
       left join plane_leg c
       on a.shipment_id = c.shipment_id and a.route_id = c.route_id
       left join warehouse_attributes w1
       on a.route_warehouse_id = w1.warehouse_id
       left join warehouse_attributes w2
       on b.leg_warehouse_id = w2.warehouse_id
       RIGHT JOIN list_legs_ds k
       on a.route_warehouse_id = k.leg_ware AND a.leg_warehouse_id = k.last_ds
group by
       w1.physical_country origin_country,
       a.leg_warehouse_id lm_warehouse_id,
       b.leg_warehouse_id fl_warehouse_id,
       c.plane_name,
       k.leg_ware,
       k.last_ds,
       trunc(a.ead_date),
       trunc(d.ead_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove `max` as you already said, since `pickup_date_ts`,as being a non-aggregated column, not-listed in the `GROUP BY` list.

Try `trunc( max(trunc(d.ead_date) - d.pickup_date_ts))`.

*Btw, it's not suggested to use column order numbers in the `GROUP BY` expression, some changes in the `SELECT` list may have an advers impact on them, rather write columns' names explicitly.*